# Component Not Rendering Correctly During Test

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-qunit

I'm writing integration tests for my Ember CLI app, and one of my tests fails every time. This is my current test:

```
// tests/integration/project-test.js
test('displays "Projects" when the user views a project from Collaborate', function() {
  visit('/collaborate');

  click('.table > tbody > tr > td > a'); // it goes to /collaborate/projects/:id
  expect(0);
});
```

When it navigates to `/collaborate/projects/:id`, I get the error "Cannot read property 'setLegend' of null." I traced that to my component:

```
// app/components/foo-comp.js
import Ember from "ember";

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  fooObject: null,
  didInsertElement: function () {
    var foo = new Foo();

    this.set('fooObject', foo);
    Ember.run.once(this, 'updateChart');
  },
  updateChart: function () {
    var foo = this.get('fooObject');
    foo.setLegend(); // this is where the error comes from
  }.observes('data','fooObject')
});
```

Note that the test does pass if I change `updateChart` to:

```
updateChart: function () {
  var foo = this.get('fooObject');

  if (foo) {
    foo.setLegend();
  }
}.observes('data','fooObject')
```

Why would it not set that variable during a test? It works fine in development and production, so I'm not sure why this is happening. I'm assuming it's because `didInsertElement` isn't triggered when the test runs. Thoughts? Ideas?

Ember version:

```
version: 0.1.12
node: 0.10.33
npm: 2.1.8
```

**Edit**

Could it be that `Foo()` is from an external module? Maybe the test doesn't have access to it, so it can't be added to the page? I doubt it, and I've already tried adding it to `.jshintrc`, but I imagine it could still be related to that. I also console logged `Foo` while running the test, and it did show up in the console.

Honestly, it is possibly related to inserting it into the DOM. I've had problems with other components initializing, so it's probably that the `didInsertElement` isn't functioning the way I think.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, maybe your test doesn't wait for everything to be loaded?

I'm not sure but you can try with:

```
test('displays "Projects" when the user views a project from Collaborate', function() {
  expect(0);
  visit('/collaborate');
  andThen(function() {
    click('.table > tbody > tr > td > a');
  });
});
```

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't work. `Foo()` is from an outside module, so is it possible it's that? I'll add that to my question.